# How do I add flavor to this amazing looking dish?

Tags: eggs, meringue

I have made an ancient pre-WWII recipe titled "Slovakian-Style Eggs." They look like fried eggs on static electricity. The whites are whipped into what is in effect a meringue, without sugar or any seasoning other than salt. This looks amazing, as you can see in the linked photo, but the failure of the recipe is the flavor is bland. I have searched in vain for any hint at how to add flavor and still maintain the amazing texture and appearance. 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/wikipix/4190731688/in/photolist-7ojAwC-9yqaRg-7oCSrh/

Comment: I enjoy adding a little Tony Chacheres to many of my recipes.

Comment: Seems like you could follow a recipe for savory meringue.  Here are some suggestions: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7461/how-are-savoury-meringues-made

Answer (score 3):

These look like a recipe I've seen going around recently called [cloud eggs](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+eggs), with the yolk nesting in well-beaten whites like it's sitting in a cloud. (I'm only including that name because it may be easier for you to Google recipes with a more modern name than your pre-WWII version, in case you're looking for flavoring inspiration.)

Whether a sweet or savory meringue, the key to adding any seasoning is very, *very* gentle folding to avoid deflating the beaten egg whites. However, you should be able to add salt, spices, and I've even seen recipes that call for grated Parmesan, as long as you fold carefully instead of stirring vigorously.